# Extract the initial part of a url if it ends with .com or .net

Tags: python, regex

I have the following input string

```
string = ['sql ddlsql144.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net',
          'fra-sql-03.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net bro',
          'esc-cca3cdr-12.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.com',
          'au-per-06a-stwp-01.per.asia.ecnahcdroffilc.com',\
          'http://go.fotrscomi.com',
          'http //go.fotrscomi.com',
          'fotrscomi.windows.computer',
          'printers-03.internal.clif 10.51.59.10 roalswinds.oionr']
```

I want the result to be

```
['ddlsql144', 
 'fra-sql-03', 
 'esc-cca3cdr-12', 
 'au-per-06a-stwp-01'
 '10.51.59.10' ]
```

Condition to match the pattern is :

- any url that ends with `.com` or `.net` should match but it should not start with `https://` or `http://` or `http //`
- only the first part of the `url` must be returned
- if there is any IP address occurs in string

I tried

```
expression = "(\w[-.a-z0-9]*)..?(?=org|net|com)"
# to extract the whole url
urls = re.findall(expression, str(string))
```

to get the initial part I used

```
re.findall('(^\w.+?)\.',str(urls))
```

But this didn't gave me the expected results.

Comment: OP, we need to talk about those spaces there.

Comment: Also, are you 100% hell-bent on using regex, or would you consider a more efficient solution?

Comment: conditions updated.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If there is a efficient solution, I definitely would like to know. Apologies for late response

Comment: No worries. I will run some benchmarks when I have a computer to work with. In general regex gives you efficiency of thought, not time or space. For the simple case you present, I suspect that a non-regex solution will be faster but not more necessarily more legible or maintainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended solution with `re.search` function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

items = ['sql ddlsql144.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net','fra-sql-03.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.net bro',
          'esc-cca3cdr-12.internal.ecnahcdroffilc.com', 'au-per-06a-stwp-01.per.asia.ecnahcdroffilc.com',
          'http://go.fotrscomi.com', 'http //go.fotrscomi.com',
          'fotrscomi.windows.computer', 'printers-03.internal.clif 10.51.59.10 roalswinds.oionr'
         ]

result = []
pat = re.compile(r'(http )?([^\s.]+)[^\s]+\.(?:org|net|com)\b|\b((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\b')
for i in items:
    m = pat.search(i)
    if m:
        if not m.group(1) and m.group(2) and not m.group(2).startswith('http'):
            result.append(m.group(2))
        elif m.group(3):
            result.append(m.group(3))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['ddlsql144', 'fra-sql-03', 'esc-cca3cdr-12', 'au-per-06a-stwp-01', '10.51.59.10']
```

Comment: I apology for not describing the condition for `10.51.59.10`, but I need this match as well. See update

Comment: Is it possible to do this when the input is string instead of list, like `str(list)`